# Why does route() works in view in this case on Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, view

Here's my environment -> Laravel 5.7, PHP 7.1, Mysql 5.7

I am new at Laravel.
I used the command of `make:auth` to use authenticate system then `login.blade.php` is made by it.
In `login.blade.php`, this line is there as default.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
```

Following the rules, I tried to find out the `Name` of `login` in `route:list` but there is no such a Name strangely.

```
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | POST      | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
```

It is supposed to be in a record of POST-method because according to `form`, it is the POST method, right??
And this application works somehow even though there is not Name in `route:list`.

I put on cords of `Router.php` in case.

```
public function auth(array $options = [])
    {
        // Authentication Routes...
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
        $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

        // Registration Routes...
        if ($options['register'] ?? true) {
            $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
            $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
        }

        // Password Reset Routes...
        if ($options['reset'] ?? true) {
            $this->resetPassword();
        }

        // Email Verification Routes...
        if ($options['verify'] ?? false) {
            $this->emailVerification();
        }
    }
```

Could you please help me out?
I am looking forward you to answer this question.
Thank you.

Comment: The route name for POST /login and GET /login is the same, and should be the same, cause they point to the same URI. The only thing it is changed is the http method but the URI is the same.

Comment: It's because route method will only generate the path to your route, it doesn't pay attention of the http method in the form, it's only a helper to generate easily the `login` path

Comment: @dparoli @Julian Metral Thank you for answering. So, Is `login` kind of omitted in the `Name` column for the POST method? If so, I completely understand that is why I could log in the page.

Comment: Yeah, the name is for the `URI` not for the combo `HTTP METHOD : URI`. This is why `POST /login` don't have a name, it has already one assigned in `GET /login`. You can always choose how to call a named route with the method you want, just be sure the method+URI is declared in your routes file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Named routes** are here only to allow the easy generation of `URLs`. So naming a route is only for easier code maintenance, it's *not mandatory*.

You have to keep in mind that the naming is only referring to the `URI` part of the route declaration, *without the method definition*.

So it is redundant naming two routes declaration with the same `URI` and different `method` because you will have to give them the *same name*. And if you don't give the same name you will have two named route with the same `URL` constructor.

This is why you see code like this:

```
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

The second line does **not** need a name because it has already one from the first.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I have one more thing to ask. The reason why the `Action`: `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login` works properly is that the server distinguishes whether the method is POST or GET automatically??

Comment: Yes any http server have to distinguish different methods. The method itself, togheter with the URL, are fundamental part of the HTTP protocol.